# asp.net HttpClient post to private API

Tags: asp.net, httpclient

I'm trying to use HttpClient to send an XML to a private API. The server said that they expected: HTML Post with the xml in a variable named “request”.

My code:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument();
//Here I create the XML file

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
// URL is the url for the private server
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
string request = document.ToString();
var httpConten = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var result = client.PostAsync("", httpConten).Result;
```

Result is returning:

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Referrer-Policy: same-origin
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2018 23:16:27 GMT
  Set-Cookie: SESSION=8dfda17c-a5c9-44c6-ae2b-d74847039f87; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 469
}}
```

Am I doing an HTML post with the XML variable named request? I contacted the server and they said they did not receive my request.

Thanks

Comment: Double check the URL. If it is deadly true, then tell if the server requires any kind of authentication -basic, token etc?

Comment: They do authentication in the XML file. They said that the issue is because I'm not submitting xml in a variable named “request”. How can I make sure that I'm doing it?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing an HTML post with the XML variable named request?

To answer your question, you aren't. You are creating a request that has your xml as it's content. The "request" variable you are defining is just in your local environment and don't appear in your request at all.

> xml in a variable named “request”

The condition itself is weird though. It could mean sending a json object, where you have property "request" and that is equal to a string which is xml, and then they parse the thing themselves.

Comment: I agree... It is very weird. Do you have an example of a json object with a property "request"?

Comment: Do you do any other requests to this api?

Comment: No, it is the only request

Comment: To be fair, you said they do authentication from xml. But in your example xml is empty, so you are getting unauthorized. Unless that's just an example.

Comment: Just an example. I build the XML. They said the XML is okay, the problem is the variable named "request". I don't know how to set a name to the content that I'm sending in a HTTP Post

Comment: HTTP messages don't have named bodies. You have headers, and then there's just a body, which can be whatever you want. You can't name the body itself. Ask them what they actually want. You are missing some information.